# Advice on tensorflow 1.13 on cuda 10.1

Tags: tensorflow

I rushed a bit and upgraded to Ubuntu 18.10, couldn't find a cuda 10.0 version for it so went for cuda 10.1... which I understand tensorflow doesn't support yet.

Would you advise reverting back to Ubuntu 18.04 or patiently waiting for a compatible tensorflow release?

Answer (score 2):

tensorflow 1.13 doesn't work with cuda 10.1 because of the following

ImportError: libcublas.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

tensorflow is looking for libcublas.so.10.0 whereas cuda provides libcublas.so.10.1.0.105.

Comment: I've now moved to tensorflow 2.0 and its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

The older cuda drivers are available here: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-archive

TensorFlow provided binaries went from CUDA 9.0 to CUDA 10.0, skipping CUDA 9.1 and 9.2. So I would not recommend waiting for CUDA 10.1 TensorFlow binaries.

It is highly likely that CUDA 10.0 would run fine on Ubuntu 18.10, but if that is not the case, then yes revert back to 18.04.

Comment: Thanks! I've install CUDA 10.0 using the 18.04 version provided, it seems to be working just fine for now. I'll report here if I spot any issues.

Comment: You can build TensorFlow 1.14 from source using CUDA 10.1. Or maybe Anaconda provides a build with supports 10.1